# Help finding a harry potter fanfic... Where Harry lives in the streets initially

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I have tried using google to find keywords, but unfortunately, no dice. And, sadly, I have misplaced the link. So it starts like this:

Harry, for reasons unknown at the time, has been living on the streets. Around 10 years old, he meets Dumbledore in an alleyway, who tells him that the Dursleys have been killed. After talking to Harry, who is suspicious as all hell, for a little while, he takes him to Snape's house. The Dursleys abuse in this story is much worse than in cannon, so after living together a little while, Snape is somewhat surprised.

Anyway that's the beginning. Later on it is revealed that the Dursleys (with the exception of Dudley) had been killed by a chemical fire started when one of them threw a cigarette into the cupboard.

Also, the deciding factor which makes Snape see that something is off with Harry is that, after he destroys Snape's personal library, and Snape, in his rage, unintentionally dislocates his sholder, Harry simply pops the shoulder back  in with "practiced ease".

In the end, Snape adopts Harry and he is sorted into Ravenclaw.

Comment: perhaps this can give a start: http://www.favoritestracker.org/publicList.php?list=7722

Answer (score 6):

### **This is [To Trust](http://www.potionsandsnitches.org/fanfiction/viewstory.php?action=printable&textsize=0&sid=3048&chapter=5), by Abie**

The Dursleys die in a chemical fire.

> The deaths of Vernon Dursley, 35, and Petunia Dursley, 33, were
>   confirmed on May 30th. According to reports, a fire had broken out in
>   their Little Whinging home between the hours of three and four AM. It
>   was found that a lit cigarette had been discarded in a cupboard
>   beneath the stairs, which had made contact with an ammonia-based
>   cleaning fluid. The son of the victims, aged 10, who had not been in
>   the home at the time, has been taken into the custody of a relative.
>
> Harry blinked, and read it again. And again.
>
> Wow. I never… A fire, from the cupboard… well, it wouldn’t have been
>   the first time he’d thrown a cigarette in there… and Dudley’s alive….

Harry destroys Snape's library.

> A fury such that Harry had never felt ripped through him. He felt it
>   in his chest, his lungs, his very heart. He had never felt such anger,
>   such all-encompassing fury that possessed a life force of its own.
>
> The anger expanded within him, and his body could no longer contain
>   it. It burst out of him in a terrific surge of furious magic.
>
> The room seemed to explode before him. The windows shattered, and
>   countless, tiny shards of glass scattered across the room. Hundreds of
>   books flew off their shelves, landing in every corner of the room,
>   piled haphazardly. The bookshelves themselves, every last one, crashed
>   to the floor with a deafening thud, the entire room shuddering. The
>   chairs and tables overturned, ink splattering everywhere.

Snape dislocates Harry's shoulder.

> Severus stood, overcome by an emotion akin to shock, staring at the
>   spot the boy had just vacated. He could tell, by the distant pounding
>   of the stairs, that the boy had not attempted to run, he’d just
>   retreated to his bedroom. What did I just do? He had, in a startling
>   fit of rage, manhandled the boy roughly enough to dislocate his
>   shoulder, and he’d likely left bruises on the boy’s arms as well.
>   Severus had never, in any sense of the word, liked children, but he’d
>   never laid a finger on any one of them, let alone done them physical
>   harm Until now.

And Harry relocates it with "practiced ease."

> He’d hurt a child. Not James Potter reincarnated, not a person of
>   equal stature and strength, but a child, and a small, underfed one at
>   that.
>
> And then, the boy had promptly shoved his shoulder back into place
>   with an air of practiced ease, as though it was something he did every
>   day.

I'm not sure whether he was sorted into Ravenclaw, though.